# Maya Orthographic Projection Matrix

Tags: python, opengl, maya, orthographic

I'm attempting to calculate maya's orthographic projection matrix. Is anyone familiar with how to calculate it? I am not interested in perspective, just orthographic camera views.

```
import math
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.OpenMaya as OpenMaya
import maya.OpenMayaUI as OpenMayaUI

# Get view matrix.
view = OpenMayaUI.M3dView.active3dView()
mayaProjMatrix = OpenMaya.MMatrix()
view.projectionMatrix(mayaProjMatrix)

print("\nMaya Projection:")
for x in xrange(0, 4):
    print(round(mayaProjMatrix(x, 0), 3),
          round(mayaProjMatrix(x, 1), 3),
          round(mayaProjMatrix(x, 2), 3),
          round(mayaProjMatrix(x, 3), 3))

Maya Projection:
(0.067, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.132, 0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0)
```

I've been researching lots of sites, but I'm not quite sure how to translate the same idea in maya (http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html#ortho).

Comment: So what is actually the question?

Comment: How to produce the same matrix manually.

Comment: Well, this matrix is just scaling in `x` and `y` and projecting everything to `z=-1` (so very bad if you pan to use this for rendering). But the scaling will totally depend on the viewport size and the image region you want to view. I really think the question "how does maya do this" is totally misleading.

Comment: I suppose the question should have been "how do you calculate an orthographic projection matrix using maya's viewport width, height, nearClipping, and farClipping values"? It could just be my lack of understanding, but it seems like maya calculates it's orthographic projections different than the examples I've seen on the net.

Comment: The matrix you have printed so far is a bit different, because it throws away the depth. You can use such a matrix also with GL, but lots of stuff like the depth test will not work. However, the near and far clipping planes are not represented in this matrix at all.

Comment: I see. How would you calculate a projection matrix like this then? This example's view width and height are 1401 by 709.

Comment: THat are not enough parameters. You need to define the image area in your scene units also. THe viewport actually only contributes the aspect ratio at this point. From the numbers given, it _might_ match (but you rounded to just 3 digits, which makes judging this a little bit unprecise). That would mean that this covers 29.85 x 15.15 area in scene units. However, this is assuming soime GL-like conventions and I'm not sure it maya follows them at this point.

Comment: Pardon my lack of knowlege in this, but how do you go about calculating the image area in maya's scene units? I've only rounded to 3 to just view the matrix not in scientific notation. A more precise version is like this:

Maya Projection:
(0.066666667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.131734838, 0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.0, -0.000200002, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.0, -1.00002, 1.0)

Comment: You should put those numbers into the real question, because they change a lot: we now don't have this weird zero column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In computer graphics, a projection matrix just defines an affine or projective transformation of some volume into a defined standard volume, typically a cube.

I don't know maya's conventions here, so I'm using GL's. The principles are the same in any case.

In GL, the viewing volume is represented by the unit cube [-1,1] along all 3 dimensions in *normalized device space*. And the projection's matrix job is to transform data into *clip space*. The difference between clip space and normalized device space is that the latter is after the perspective divide. However, since you don't want a perspecive but just an ortho matrix and the divisor will just be constantly 1 - so in this case, we can consider normalized device space and clip space as the same.

Now taking your matrix (the more precise version from the comments, the one you pasted in the question actually makes it impossible to reconstruct z) and multiplying a point to it leads to:

```
(0.066666667  0.0          0.0          0.0    )  (x)
(0.0          0.131734838  0.0          0.0    )  (y)
(0.0          0.0         -0.000200002 -1.00002)  (z) 
(0.0          0.0          0.0          1.0    )  (1)

x' =  0.066666667 * x
y' =  0.131734838 * y
z' = -0.000200002 * z -1.00002
```

So this matrix is very nice in that it simply can be inverted by inverting each equation separately. All you need to find out are the `x` `y` and `z` for the edges of the viewing volume in clip space, so `x'=-1`, `x'=1`, `y'=-1` and so on.

This results in the viewing volume [-15,15] in x, [-7.591,7.591] in y (matching the aspect ratio of 1401/709 as you mentioned in the comments) and [-0.1,-5000] in z. In typical GL terms, this matrix is the result of:

```
ortho(-15, 15, -15/aspect, 15/aspect, 0.1, 5000)
```

(the z values for clip near and clip far are negated by convention, as the camera is supposed to look along `-z`, and the clip values are distances).

And all of that is actually explained in the link you gave. I would have added that very same link here, if it wasn't already in the quesiton...

Answer (score 1):

I figured I'll post the maya code I'm using. Apparently there's orthographic attribute in maya that helps calculate this called "Orthographic Width" based off derhass's answer.

```
# Get view matrix.
view = OpenMayaUI.M3dView.active3dView()
mayaProjMatrix = OpenMaya.MMatrix()
view.projectionMatrix(mayaProjMatrix)

# Get camera MFnDagPath.
dagCam = OpenMaya.MDagPath()
view.getCamera(dagCam)

width = float(view.portWidth())
height = float(view.portHeight())
aspect = width/height

n = cmds.getAttr("%s.nearClipPlane" % dagCam.fullPathName())
f = cmds.getAttr("%s.farClipPlane" % dagCam.fullPathName())

w = 2.0/cmds.getAttr("%s.orthographicWidth" % dagCam.fullPathName())
h = w * aspect
z = -2.0/(f-n)
v = -1.0 * ((f + n) / (f-n))

mat = [0.0] * 16
mat[0] = w
mat[1] = 0.0
mat[2] = 0.0
mat[3] = 0.0

mat[4] = 0.0
mat[5] = h
mat[6] = 0.0
mat[7] = 0.0

mat[8] = 0.0
mat[9] = 0.0
mat[10] = z
mat[11] = 0.0

mat[12] = 0.0
mat[13] = 0.0
mat[14] = v
mat[15] = 1.0

projMatrix = OpenMaya.MMatrix()
OpenMaya.MScriptUtil().createMatrixFromList(mat, projMatrix)

print("\nMaya Projection:")
for x in xrange(0, 4):
    print(round(mayaProjMatrix(x, 0), 9),
          round(mayaProjMatrix(x, 1), 9),
          round(mayaProjMatrix(x, 2), 9),
          round(mayaProjMatrix(x, 3), 9))

print("\nMy Projection:")
for x in xrange(0, 4):
    print(round(projMatrix(x, 0), 9),
          round(projMatrix(x, 1), 9),
          round(projMatrix(x, 2), 9),
          round(projMatrix(x, 3), 9))

Maya Projection:
(0.04116922, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.061226019, 0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.0, -0.000200002, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.0, -1.00002, 1.0)

My Projection:
(0.04116922, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.061226019, 0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.0, -0.000200002, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.0, -1.00002, 1.0)
```